# How to read log file of all the hosts in a marklogic cluster and search for a particular keyword and count the results

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf, marklogic-10

I had a requirement where I need to read the application log files of all host in cluster and search for a particular keyword and get the count of all.

Log file in question is 9005_ErrorLog.txt and will look like below (I am searching for keyword "SERVICE-EXIT: ManchesterUnited")

Host 1 (9005_ErrorLog.txt),

```
2023-03-15 00:48:01.804 Info: SERVICE-ENTRY: ManchesterUnited
2023-03-15 00:48:01.840 Info: SERVICE-EXIT: ManchesterUnited
2023-03-15 00:53:00.874 Info: SERVICE-ENTRY: ManchesterUnited
2023-03-15 00:53:00.906 Info: SERVICE-EXIT: ManchesterUnited
2023-03-15 01:28:01.946 Info: SERVICE-ENTRY: ManchesterUnited
2023-03-15 01:28:01.954 Info: SERVICE-EXIT: ManchesterUnited
```

no of counts matching in host 1 9005_ErrorLog.txt = 3

Host 2 (9005_ErrorLog.txt)

```
2023-03-15 00:48:01.804 Info: SERVICE-ENTRY: ManchesterUnited
2023-03-15 00:48:01.840 Info: SERVICE-EXIT: ManchesterUnited
```

no of counts matching host 2 9005_ErrorLog.txt = 1

Host 3 (9005_ErrorLog.txt)

```
2023-03-15 00:48:01.804 Info: SERVICE-ENTRY: ManchesterUnited
2023-03-15 00:48:01.840 Info: SERVICE-EXIT: ManchesterUnited
```

no of counts matching host 3 9005_ErrorLog.txt = 1

Total Count = 5 ( I need this to be the final result of Xquery code)

I wrote below script to get the count from individual host file

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

let $error-log := "/ML-master/Logs/9005_ErrorLog.txt"
let $keyword := "SERVICE-EXIT: ManchesterUnited"


for $line in fn:tokenize(xdmp:filesystem-file($error-log), '\r?\n')
where contains($line, $keyword)

return
$line
```

Also, to get all the log file from single xquery code in Query console, I am able to do that using below code

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
for $hid in xdmp:hosts()
let $h := xdmp:host-name($hid)
return 
xdmp:filesystem-file("file://" || $h || "/"||xdmp:data-directory($hid)||"/Logs/9005_ErrorLog.txt")
```

How can I integrate both the scripts into one single Xquery module which will search a keyword "SERVICE-EXIT: ManchesterUnited" in all the 3 host 9005_ErrorLog.txt files and count the no of matches and give us the final count of matches = 5.

Comment: You can do that in one for loop in your second module - instead of returning the filename, just construct the filename and then use your code for tokenizing its contents and looking for the string you're interested in. Note though that you might be better off setting up a dedicated log analysis tool like Splunk for this kind of use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also agree with David suggestions. But if you are still looking something as per your code snippet, this should work:

```
let $error-log := "/ML-master/Logs/9005_ErrorLog.txt"
return
sum(
  for $hid in xdmp:hosts()
  let $h := xdmp:host-name($hid)
  return 
    count(
      for $line in fn:tokenize(xdmp:filesystem-file("file://" || $h || "/"||xdmp:data-directory($hid)||"/Logs/9005_ErrorLog.txt"), '\r?\n')
      where contains($line, $keyword)
      return $line
    )
)
```

Answer (score 3):

I woud suggest that you consider using some syslog facility that consolidates all of the logs for you.  Then use some standard log analysis from there.

For MarkLogic, I would use the REST endpoint [GET /manage/v2/logs](https://docs.marklogic.com/10.0/REST/GET/manage/v2/logs)

You can then limit via regex and count results. You will need to play with the hosts param option to see if it works as expected. If not, then hit each host separately.